# How to install Synaptic Package Manager?

Tags: software-center, software-installation

I tried to install Synaptic Package Manager but I get the following error message:

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved.
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. 
Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
```

Comment: Well does not your synaptic pacckage manager is installed? It seems you have your package already installed you are searching for. Goto System > Administration > "Synaptic Package Manager" and see if there is the thing you are searching here for

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Answer (score 66):

On the terminal type in the following commands (one line at a time) >>

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Comment: I'd add `-f` to the update and upgrade commands if I was having problems.

Comment: i prefer not to do the upgrade

Comment: why the upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

Just go here and install offline way if this helps.
[Synaptic packages for 12.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=synaptic%20)

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ: the link isn't a link to some instructions, it's a link to `.deb` files.

Comment: why would you need any instructions if you got a .deb file already? Its the most simplest thing to install a deb file on ubuntu I guess

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening then you either have a package version that is lower than the required dependency version or one of your packages is broken.

You can try fixing the packages by running your update manager and checking for updates and installing them.