# How can I remove Unity web apps?

Tags: unity, webapps

I recently installed Ubuntu and all has been great, except for the web apps feature.

I've tried adding a few web apps, but it's very buggy and not a very good experience. I'm also tired of being asked to add a website as an web app. How can I remove web apps from Ubuntu entirely? I use both Chromium and Firefox.

Answer (score 10):

### Ubuntu 13.10 and 14.04

To avoid being asked for webapp integration you can use the following command, open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.unity.webapps integration-allowed false
```

Tested on both releases with Firefox/Chromium + Launchpad, Facebook and Youtube. No popup asking for a webapp integration.

### Removing existing webapps

We can't just remove all packages beginning with `unity-webapps-` as some of them are runtime dependencies of Unity or other packages (like the Ubuntu SDK which requires `unity-webapps-qml`)

A safe way is to remove such installed packages not belonging to the gnome [section](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive.html#s-subsections):

```
sudo apt-get remove $(dpkg-query -W -f='${db:Status-Abbrev} ${binary:Package} ${Section}\n' unity-webapps-* | awk '{if ($1 == "ii" && $3 != "gnome") {print $2}}')
```

Answer (score 5):

If what you want is removing them, you can do it in two ways.

### Manual

With this method you should copy and paste the packages names.

```
apt-cache search unity-webapps
```

This will give you a list of all your webapps. Just remove the ones that you don't like with `sudo apt-get remove packages`.

### Automatic

This will remove any package that its name starts with `unity-webapps`:

```
sudo aptitude remove '?and(?name(^unity-webapps), ?not(?or(?name(^unity-webapps-common), ?or(?name(^unity-webapps-qml), ?name(^unity-webapps-service$)))))'
```

This archive the same, just that more fancy:

```
sudo aptitude remove '?depends(unity-webapps-common)'
```

You should have installed aptitude by now with `sudo apt-get install aptitude`.

### The wrong way

All webapps depends on the same package, `unity-webapps-common`, so if you remove it it should remove all those packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-webapps-common
```

This will remove the `ubuntu-desktop` package and `unity-asset-pool` which may be undesirable.

Comment: I'd not suggest this solution as it leaves the system in a very bad state if you’re developing Touch apps as it breaks several dependencies on 14.04 (See http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7371611/)

Comment: now the first command does nothing (No packages will be installed, upgraded or removed).

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7372664/ and http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7372667/

Comment: @SylvainPineau it doesn't do anything because there's nothing to do. All packages except `unity-webapps-launchpad` are removed. That's why it does nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation but I'm still puzzled by the command filtering by package namse as you can't be 100% sure to match all corner cases.

Comment: @SylvainPineau sadly, that's the only way to go. Other possible matches has many more packages than just this and are more difficult to maintain. You can try `sudo aptitude search '?depends(unity-webapps-common)'` which is a bit more restrictive, but I'm not sure if you add the webapps development packages to the mix. BTW, you can always replace `remove` for `search` to verify what will be done.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a filter using the debian Section of those packages.

Answer (score 1):

## Though the Command Line (quicker)

First open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and these commands:

### Remove all of the web apps

---

```
 sudo apt-get remove $(dpkg-query -W -f='${db:Status-Abbrev} ${binary:Package} ${Section}\n' unity-webapps-* | awk '{if ($1 == "ii" && $3 != "gnome" && $2 != "unity-webapps-service" && $2 != "unity-webapps-common") {print $2}}')
 sudo apt-get remove xul-ext-unity unity-chromium-extension
```

---

### Remove some of the web apps

```
apt-cache search unity-webapps
```

This will list all of your packages that began with `unity-webapps` Most of them will be webapps but not all (8). Do not remove the ones that it is not webapps this includes (`libunity-webapps-dev`, `libunity-webapps-doc`, `libunity-webapps0`, `unity-webapps-common`, `unity-webapps-qml`, `unity-webapps-qml-doc` `unity-webapps-qml-examples`, and the last one `unity-webapps-service`.) remove the ones that you what by `sudo apt-get remove webapp1 webapp2`... replace webappx with the name of the webapp that you want to get rad of.  Note you can list them.  **DO NOT REMOVE `unity-webapps-common`, and `unity-webapps-service` IT WILL REMOVE UNITY!**

**Disable notifications from web apps (optional)**

```
 gsettings set com.canonical.unity.webapps integration-allowed false
 gsettings set com.canonical.unity.webapps allowed-domains []
```

---

## Do it Graphically

### Remove some or all of the web apps

Open Synaptic Package Manager if you don't have it install fellow this [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/132054/48372).  After that search for `unity-webapps-` by hitting on the button that says "search"

[image]

You will get a window like this.  Just type in `unity-webapps-` into the text box. Than hit the button that says "search"  Just hit the button that says "Mark" and keep doing it if it is necessary.

[image]

After that Right click on any package that is green box next to it. The green box means it is installed. Select `remove package` to remove the webapp that you what to get rad of.  If you want to get raid of all of them. Than research for `xul-ext-unity`, and `unity-chromium-extension`.  **DO NOT REMOVE `unity-webapps-common`, and `unity-webapps-service` IT WILL REMOVE UNITY!**

[image]

After that, hit the button that says "Apply"  And you will get a window like this, and just hit the button that says "Apply", too.

[image]

**Disable notifications from web apps (optional)**

First open to Dconf Editor, and if you don't have it install fellow this [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/191013/48372), than go to `com` > `cononical` > `unity` > `webapps`.  After that unchecked the check box `integration-allowed`

[image]

Clear every thing in the string `allowed domains` by double clicking on it and it should change it from a text field to a textbox.

**[image]**

---

## Sources

- http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/10/how-to-remove-webapps-in-ubuntu-1210.html (For Disable notifications)
- http://www.gaggl.com/2013/06/remove-ubuntu-webapps-integration-features/ (For removing the option in Firefox and Chromium.)
- https://askubuntu.com/a/458004/48372 (For the command `sudo apt-get remove $(dpkg-query -W -f='${db:Status-Abbrev} ${binary:Package} ${Section}\n' unity-webapps-* | awk '{if ($1 == "ii" && $3 != "gnome" && $2 != "unity-webapps-service" && $2 != "unity-webapps-common") {print $2}}')`  I just modified it so it wounldn't remove `"unity-webapps-service` or `unity-webapps-common` Thanks to [Sylvain Pineau](https://askubuntu.com/users/32239/sylvain-pineau) for proving the original command)

Comment: Both methods won't work as `unity-webapps-common` depends on `unity-webapps-service`. So removing `unity-webapps-service` will also remove `unity-webapps-common` AND Unity (See http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7371559/)

Comment: This is the second time that you copy my own answer, I don't appreciate this type of behavior. I downvoted your answer simply because I does not work and I explained why. Please revert your vote or at least explain where I 'm wrong. I'll let moderator decide what to do with plagiator behaviour.

Comment: @SylvainPineau I wasn't paying attention to other answers, I got it from a blog.  and Than I showed how to do it.

Comment: First of all thanks for referencing your sources. My apt command didn't come from a blog though as I created it yesterday per Jorge's request. Anyway you don't need to explicitly filter `unity-webapps-service` and `unity-webapps-common` as both belong to the gnome section.

Answer (score 0):

Run from a terminal (not sudo)

> gsettings set com.canonical.unity.webapps allowed-domains []

You're done.