# Disable Facebook plug-in on default Firefox

Tags: 12.10, firefox, plugins

This may a Firefox question rather than Ubuntu but since the plug-in seem to be integrated with the Ubuntu status bar so I think I should try my luck here.
Just update to Firefox 17 and not sure why now when I go to Facebook a icon show in launcher and a entry for Facebook at the top-right conner under the message icon.
How can I disable this plug-in? It not in the list of my Extensions or Plugins list!
**Update** Here is an screenshot:
[image]

Comment: an image could help us much .:D

Comment: Tks, I just upload a screenshot. I can not take a screenshot when click on the message icon, not sure why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unity webapps feature of Unity. [Here is a related post on OMGUbuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/list-of-that-websites-support-unitys-new-web-apps-feature)

This feature is totally unrelated to the firefox version you are using. You can stop the integration by disabling Unity webapps extension from Firefox addons.

Firefox 17 adds a social integration option. However, this does not integrate with Unity environment the way you have shown.

Related Questions

- [How do I get the browser to reask me to integrate with a website?](https://askubuntu.com/q/165688/45659)
- [How do I remove a website from Ubuntu's web applications?](https://askubuntu.com/q/166655/45659)
- [How can I remove Unity web apps?](https://askubuntu.com/q/214755/45659)

Comment: I think this may be **the correct answer** but I can't be sure because I'm not using Unity.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by entering `about:config` in the address bar of Firefox and hitting `enter`. You'll get a warning, but just okay that.
Then, enter `social` in the search bar of the page that is now open. You'll then see just a few lines like this (I've inserted spaces to make things non-clickable):

```
social.activation.whitelist;h t t p s ://ww w.facebook.com  
social.active;true  
social.enabled;true  
social.manifest.facebook;{"origin":"h t t p s ://www.fac ebook.com","name":"Facebook Messenger","workerURL":"h  t t p s://www.facebook.com/desktop/fbdesktop2/socialfox/fbworker.js.php","iconURL":"d a t a :image/x-icon;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8%2F9hAAAAX0lEQVQ4jWP4 %2F%2F8%2FAyUYTFhHzjgDxP9JxGeQDSBVMxgTbUBCxer%2Fr999%2BQ8DJBuArJksA9A10s8AXIB oA0B%2BR%2FY%2FjD%2BEwoBoA1yT5v3PbdmCE8MAshhID%2FUMoDgzUYIBj0Cgi7ar4coAAAAAS UVORK5CYII%3D","sidebarURL":"https://www.facebook.com/desktop/fbdesktop2/?socialfox=true"}  
social.sidebar.open;true  
social.sidebar.unload_timeout_ms;10000  
social.toast-notifications.enabled;true
```

What you then need to do is to highlight, one at a time, the lines with `social.active;true` and  `social.enabled;true` and hit `enter` each time. Hitting `enter` will toggle between `true` and `false`. You can do so for whichever additional lines you wish.

(Note the long line of code. That one draws the Facebook icon because it's a data URL.)

I must stress that my code above is slightly different than what you may see because I'm using Firefox 17 (beta) and not Firefox 17 (stable) and in my version **Facebook is off by default**.

After you've done your changes, close the about:config tab (or window) and things should be fine after you restart the browser.

Oh, and while I was writing this answer you provided an image. Now, I'm not using Unity, which has a few "social" activities of its own but still what I've suggested may help!

Comment: nice explanation vasa1 . +1 .