# How to remove "Amazon"?

Tags: shopping-lens

I wanted to remove "Amazon" from my 14.04 and tried to follow the instructions given here:

- [How can I remove Amazon search results from the dash or disable the feature?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192269/how-can-i-remove-amazon-search-results-from-the-dash-or-disable-the-feature)

However, even after logging off and loggin back in, I see that I get the updates to "Amazon":

[image: amazon updates]

"Online search results" have been disabled in Security and Privacy settings. I even tried to remove it from the software center by using the button provided in the above question which says there is no package named `unity-lens-shopping`. And if I again try to remove `unity-lens-shopping` from the terminal using `sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-shopping`, `unity-lens-home` is selected and nothing is actually removed and I get the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'unity-scope-home' instead of 'unity-lens-shopping'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
```

<sub>I just ignore the 29 packages to be upgraded, for now, should be unrelated(?)</sub>

Trying to remove `unity-lens-home` I get a `E: Unable to locate package unity-lens-home` error.

How do I completely remove the shopping app from 14.04 to stop receiving updates for this application?

Comment: Try to remove `unity-scope-home` by running `sudo apt-get remove unity-scope-home`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: it's `unity-scope-home` not `unity-lens-home`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: It says that would remove `ubuntu-desktop`,  `unity`,  `unity-scope-home` from the system.

Comment: Maybe you're tired of this topic, but, this question is _not a duplicate_. They say they already tried the instructions in http://askubuntu.com/questions/192269/how-can-i-remove-amazon-search-results-from-the-dash-or-disable-the-feature. Also I can confirm it doesn't work in 14.04. I see the same issue attempting to remove `unity-scope-home`.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. If it is, there needs to be a link to a different article than the one pointed to now. That link is outdated and doesn't help with this issue in 15.10.

Comment: The correct answer, given below, isn't provided as an answer in the other question (only as a comment), so this won't be a duplicate once the title is made more specific.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It seems I need to remove `unity-webapps-common` to remove the shopping lens, including amazon.

To remove `unity-webapps-common`, open the Software center and type "Amazon" and remove the application with the Amazon logo as the application icon or open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-webapps-common
```

Comment: It looks like there are good reasons not to do it, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/214755/how-can-i-remove-unity-web-apps

Answer (score 14):

The following command worked on my computer.

```
sudo apt-get purge unity-lens-shopping
```

if it doesn't work,

```
sudo apt-get purge unity-webapps-common
```

Comment: I had to remove unity-webapps-common to remove amazon.

Comment: Same here had to remove unity-webapps before it disappeared. Surprisingly my dash search is much much much faster. Good job muhasturk