# How to completely remove Amazon from my Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-center, amazon

Though I could find some answer in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192269/how-can-i-remove-amazon-search-results-from-the-dash-or-disable-the-feature). Its not doing anything what I was intended to do.
When I try to run the command **sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-shopping**.
I have the result as shown [image: screenshot]
Another method was to uninstall it from **Ubuntu Software Center**.
But when I go to **Ubuntu Software Center** I do not find any results for **Amazon** even in the **Installed** Section. Why is that? I am providing Screenshots below [image] Screenshot showing **Installed** section which does not contain **Amazon** [image]

Comment: You need to remove unity-webapps-common to remove amazon. Check this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/450398/how-to-remove-amazon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove "Amazon"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/450398/how-to-remove-amazon)

Answer (score 2):

Amazon has been installed into the Unity desktop as part of a package called Unity-Webapps-Common.

You could if you wanted to, open a terminal window and run the following command:

```
$ sudo apt purge ubuntu-web-launchers
```

However, it's **not recommended**. The unity-webapps-common is a metapackage containing lots of other packages. If you uninstall this application then you will lose other things that you may need.

Instead, try to remove any files related to amazon manually.

Open a terminal window and type in the following commands:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop
sudo rm /usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/unity-webapps-amazon/Amazon.user.js
sudo rm /usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/unity-webapps-amazon/manifest.json
```

[Source](https://www.lifewire.com/remove-amazon-application-from-ubuntu-4134329)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove workspacesclient
```

and then remove any packages left by using:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```