# How do I remove libav files?

Tags: software-recommendation, uninstall

I just installed 12.04 and can not watch YouTube.

I was advised to install "Ubuntu restricted extras" from Ubuntu Software Center. But, during the installation, I got the warning that Libav codec library ( libav codec 53 )   and Libav utility Library ( libav util 51 )  should be removed before installing "Restricted Extras".

How do I go about removing these libraries? Thank You for Your patience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use synaptic as a Graphical User Interface ([How to install Synaptic Package Manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131979/how-to-install-synaptic-package-manager)) or the commandline to find and uninstall these libraries.

In the commandline do `apt-cache search libav`. See what libraries are found and remove (or purge) these as follows `sudo apt-get remove packageName` where you replace *packageName* with the results you found *and* want to delete.

After the removal you might want to run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get autoremove`. Note that any software depending on *libav* might either no longer be fully functional or might be removed.

Enjoy an libav-free system.