# How to install Synaptic package manager that I have already downloaded the package using Windows?

Tags: software-center, synaptic

I have downloaded the synaptic package manager using Windows7. I only just installed Ubuntu recently. I heard that Synaptic can help me in installing software since using the terminal is very difficult. Then I searched for synaptic in Dash home but I can't find it. I downloaded the synaptic package. Can you please help me installing synaptic offline?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may have to mount the Windows Drives (C:, D:) in Ubuntu to access the files. Has this been done?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the [Ubuntu Software Center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Software_Center) is used for installing packages and/or new software. Try looking for "Ubuntu Software Center" in the dash instead of synaptic package manger.

If you really want to install synaptic package mangager, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131979/how-to-install-synaptic-package-manager)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to install synaptic, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Once done, just search for synaptic in Dash, and when you start it, just enter your password, and you're set.

[image]

For The Ubuntu Software Center, just click on the icon shown in the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just install [gdebi Package Installer](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gdebi/).

[image]Right click the package and click install.