# Using Ubuntu Software Center seems to force my laptop to a black screen then reopens login screen

Tags: software-center, system

First of all I am new to the world of Ubuntu, it is pretty much my first time using it, ever.

The system seems to be running very stable, but I have run across one weird problem that I'm not quite sure what's the cause of.

Whenever I use the Ubuntu Software Center, after a few seconds of use (this can vary a bit, but it is usually not long), my laptop enters a black screen, and then after a few seconds enters the Ubuntu startup screen where you log in, almost as if the entire OS restarted.

I would love to provide debug information but I'm not quite sure how to, so if there's anything that could help please ask and I will edit the question with additional details :)

Thank you all for the help!

[EDIT]

I have now added the dmesg log output. It can be found here:
[DMESG Log Output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5738159/)

[EDIT] - Hardware Details

I am running Ubuntu on an intel-based Mac, more specifically MacBook 8,1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the output of some of your logs to gauge possible issues.

A good start is the `dmesg` log.

Type the following to get the last 2000 lines of the log, if the problem occurred more than a day ago 2000 lines might not be enough lines. Ideally you do this after the problem occurs so we have a snapshot of the most recent issue.

```
dmesg | tail -n 2000 > output.txt
```

This will generate a file called `output.txt`

Instead of adding that output to your question use Ubuntu paste bin http://paste.ubuntu.com/ which will give you a link that you can paste into your question

Comment: Thank you for the guidance :) I have edited my original post with the link to the output. I did this right after having experienced the crash, so it should be as recent as possible.

Comment: @Bitious As it seems you are running a Mac I recommend adding details of what modle you have to your original question just incase there are known hardware compatibility issues. Log says Apple Inc. MacBookPro8,1

Comment: ah yes that's correct, and yes the model is indeed 8,1. I have added this information to the original post :) Thank you again!

Comment: @Bitious Can't see anything obvious. To get you over the issue you can install another package manager to help you out while you get this fixed. Try http://askubuntu.com/questions/131979/how-to-install-synaptic-package-manager to install an alternate, and better, package manager. Could even use that to re-install software center

Comment: All right, I will have a look at it :) Thank you for your time though, it is much appriciated.