# mouse and touchpad settings missing

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, system-settings

I am using the latest version of **ubuntu 14.04** in the new **lenovo Z510 ideapad** laptop. I came across this problem while i was trying to enable my **two-finger swipe** action. Usually the **mouse and touchpad** setting will have separate columns for mouse and touchpad as shown here:

[image]  
<sup>from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248290/enable-both-edge-scrolling-and-two-finger-scrolling-for-touchpad/373134#373134) link</sup>

Whereas in my case there is no two parts. Just one, as shown.

[image: img]

Now can I get my settings back to normal, as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248290/enable-both-edge-scrolling-and-two-finger-scrolling-for-touchpad/373134#373134)? Also, is it possible to enable both **edge scrolling** and **two-finger scrolling** without the use of third party apps like touchegg? If so, how?

Comment: have you tried the commands in [that link you got the picture from](http://askubuntu.com/a/248304/178596)?  Just as the options are not shown does always mean that they are not available...

Comment: yes. when i try the first command it shows this "Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?"

Comment: Have you tried searching for and/or installing any drivers? e.g. `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` *(which may be default, already installed, dunno)*

Comment: i tried the commands in [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/131979/how-to-install-synaptic-package-manager) link. no luck.

Comment: [synaptic](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic/) is a package manager, not a touch pad driver..

Comment: synaptic package manager has been installed by default

Comment: Basically try running `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`. Also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad#Troubleshooting

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem. I am having exactly same problem for my Lenovo Idea Flex 15.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me just 1-2 hours ago. I've had installed Ubuntu 14.04 for a month and it was working perfect and today suddenly the touchpad stop working like it had. I'm re-installing Ubuntu tomorrow

Comment: I am having the same issue. The touchpad settings is missing in my ASUS X455LD laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get back the touchpad and mouse settings in your control panel.

You can simply install it either from synaptic package manager or by using the following apt command

```
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

If you are facing the problem with the settings just remove the mouse and touchpad settings file by the following command

```
rm -fr ~/.gconf/desktop/gnome/peripherals/mouse
```

Hope this will help you better to resolve your issues.

Comment: Package not found

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on how your touchpad is recognized - it looks the same with my HP Envy x360 15'. You will have more GUI options with [gpointing-device-settings](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gpointing-device-settings/) or Touchpad-indicator.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make sure the touch pad is active? Also, check and make sure synapics installed like it should have, you can check in the Ubuntu Software Center tool, just open it up, and type synaptics, you should see a small green circle with a check mark in it, showing that it is installed. If it's not there, just install it.

As for enabling both side and 2 finger scrolling, there is way to do that natively in Ubuntu, you would need third party apps to do it.

Comment: yeah my synaptics is not istalled. there are many downloads avainlabe in the software center. can you tell me which one is the most ideal?

Comment: according to the link sent in the above comments, my synaptic package manager has been installed.

Comment: not the package manager, it's called synaptics, not synaptic, I know it's confusing, it's just 1 letter difference, but that one letter makes a big difference with what you install. So look for synaptics, exactly, you can use synaptic package manager if you installed it, I find it to be easier to find programs in in it.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the Debian packages so it may be different for you, but I doubt it.

```
   apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Have you tried using a synaptics configuration file instead?
Here is an example of mine in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d

```
       Section "InputClass"
       Identifier      "Touchpad"                     
       MatchIsTouchpad "yes"                           
       Driver          "synaptics"                     
       Option          "MinSpeed"              "0.5"
       Option          "MaxSpeed"              "1.0"
       Option          "TapButton1"            "1"
       Option          "VertEdgeScroll"        "1"
       EndSection
```

Here I just set the speed and vertical scrolling. The settings you want are

```
   "VertTwoFingerScroll"
   "HorizTwoFingerScroll"
```

I don't see how this is different from using the program you are already using, but it is always useful to know what is going on!

Oops! I didn't see that someone has already beaten me to it! Sorry!