# Enable Two Fingers Scrolling For Touchpad in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics, scrolling

So few days ago I installed Ubuntu 16.04 for the first time and I am a newbie on this OS. I've been trying to set up my Touchpad well but I could not do it.

I can not activate two fingers scrolling and sensitivity is very high. Try looking at the menu but not mouse touchpad tab appears me. Try through the Terminal but most of the time appeared this message: could not find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded? and other times nothing happened.

I have searched many places but nothing seems to help, plus I find it a bit difficult to handle myself in this new operating system because I have very little knowledge so sometimes I dont know how to do certain things

I have an ASUS K555U.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the option `Mouse and Touch pad` in `System Settings`. `System Settings` can be accessed from the dash. From there you can change *Pointer Speed*, *Two finger scrolling* etc.

Comment: Try unity-tweak-tool. You may find it there if not here. Install it by typing "apt get install unity-tweak-tool".

Comment: When I open system settings only thing I get to see are 4 icons: Language Support, Printers, Firewall Configuration and Software & Updates.

Comment: I am using 16.04.1 I have a lot of other options. Reinstall the SYSTEM SETTINGS by following the things by doing the following in the terminal "sudo apt remove unity-control-center" and then after it's removed "sudo apt install unity-control-center". I should bring everything back.

Comment: You may want to check your system settings after you unistall unity-control-center. After I did it, it showed gnome settings. Just check if you get it and tell me.

Comment: I follow the things you said but nothing change. When i see the `xinput list` it seems that the system doesn't recognize my Touchpad because it appears like: FTE1001:00 0B05:0101.

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Comment: If not, I found a link [that may solve your problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/469667/mouse-and-touchpad-settings-missing).