# haskell-platform unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

Trying to install `haskell-platform` by using `sudo apt-get install haskell-platform` on 14.04 LTS.

The error I'm getting:

```
jared@jared-N550JK:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get install haskell-platform

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

`libcheese-gtk23 : Depends: libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 (>= 0.91.8) but it is not going  to be installed
 Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed

 libcheese7 : Depends: libclutter-gst-2.0-0 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: gstreamer1.0-clutter but it is not going to be installed

 libclutter-1.0-0 : Depends: libcogl-pango15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed

E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held     packages.
```

The only other sources/PPAs I have installed are for Spotify-linux and Google Chrome. I've also looked at a lot of other threads about unmet dependencies that have not solved my problem, including using apt-get clean, apt-get install -f, etc.

Any ideas? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I know this might be a silly question, but did you do `apt-get update` before doing this?

Comment: This looks very unrelated to `haskell`. Is your package data base in order? What does `apt-get install -f` say?

Comment: Konstantine, yes, I did do apt-get update :)
Joachim, this is what it says:

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Does http://askubuntu.com/questions/588695/cant-install-libglew-dev-because-libcheese-and-libclutter-dont-have-the-requir help you?

Comment: That did it, Joachim. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If you add that comment as an answer, I will mark this as solved.