# Ubuntu 16.04.1 with AMD APU not detecting VGA after post

Tags: drivers, 16.04, amd-graphics, amd-processor

After posting fine and showing me the grub menu, my monitor shows "No signal". I've done the "nomodeset" trick, and that's how I'm typing this post out, but I don't want this to become a permanent 'solution'. I've tried downgrading to 14.04.5 (the only 14.04 ISO I could find on ubuntu.com for some reason), and ended up with the same problem. I decided I'd dual boot 14.04.5 and 16.04.1 just so I can switch back and forth if I need to (they're using the same partition for the home folder).

When on 14.04 I couldn't install the fglrx drivers because of unmet dependencies (like this one [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598002/cannot-install-xserver-xorg-video-dummy-on-ubuntu14-04)). I switched back to 16.04, and tried the radeon and amdgpu drivers, with no luck.

One weird thing, is that if I plug my HDMI television into the MOBO, along with the VGA cable, they both work fine (on 16.04, haven't been able to test this on 14.04). I noticed this problem last week when I gave up my HDMI monitor.

I'm using an [AMD A8-7600](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/nqYXsY/amd-cpu-ad7600ybjabox), with no discrete GPU.
[Here's my entire parts list for the sake of brevity](http://pcpartpicker.com/list/LkLwzM).

Here's my `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

```
[    12.844] 
X.Org X Server 1.18.3
Release Date: 2016-04-04
[    12.844] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    12.844] Build Operating System: Linux 3.13.0-92-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    12.844] Current Operating System: Linux phoenix 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64
[    12.845] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic root=UUID=20d1a670-d7b6-4897-8027-0ec9c633b0ab ro nomodeset vga=792
[    12.845] Build Date: 22 July 2016  07:50:34AM
[    12.845] xorg-server 2:1.18.3-1ubuntu2.3 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    12.845] Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
[    12.845]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    12.845] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    12.845] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Sep 12 13:02:15 2016
[    12.907] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    12.907] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    12.930] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    12.930] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    12.930] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    12.930] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    12.931] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    12.931] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    12.931] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    12.931] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    12.931] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    12.931] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    12.931]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    12.931] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    12.931]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    12.931] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    12.932]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    12.932] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    12.932]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    12.932] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    12.932]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    12.932] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    12.932] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    12.932] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    12.932] (II) Loader magic: 0x562635159da0
[    12.932] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    12.932]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    12.932]    X.Org Video Driver: 20.0
[    12.932]    X.Org XInput driver : 22.1
[    12.932]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[    12.932] (++) using VT number 7

[    12.932] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[    12.933] (--) PCI:*(0:0:1:0) 1002:1313:1458:d000 rev 0, Mem @ 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd0000000/8388608, 0xfeb00000/262144, I/O @ 0x0000f000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    12.934] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    12.939] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    13.070] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    13.070]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    13.070]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 9.0
[    13.070] (==) AIGLX enabled
[    13.070] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 0
[    13.070] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[    13.070] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[    13.070] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[    13.070] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    13.070] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[    13.070] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module ati
[    13.070] (II) UnloadModule: "ati"
[    13.070] (II) Unloading ati
[    13.070] (EE) Failed to load module "ati" (module does not exist, 0)
[    13.070] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    13.070] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    13.070] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    13.070]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.18.3
[    13.070]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    13.070]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    13.071] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    13.071] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    13.071] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    13.071]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 0.4.4
[    13.071]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    13.071]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    13.071] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    13.071] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[    13.071] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    13.071] (II) Unloading vesa
[    13.071] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[    13.071] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 0
[    13.071] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[    13.071] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[    13.071] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[    13.071] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    13.071] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[    13.071] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module ati
[    13.071] (II) UnloadModule: "ati"
[    13.071] (II) Unloading ati
[    13.071] (EE) Failed to load module "ati" (module does not exist, 0)
[    13.071] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    13.071] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    13.071] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    13.071]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.18.3
[    13.071]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    13.071]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    13.071] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    13.071] (II) Unloading modesetting
[    13.071] (II) Failed to load module "modesetting" (already loaded, 0)
[    13.071] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    13.071] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    13.071] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    13.071]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 0.4.4
[    13.071]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    13.071]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    13.071] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    13.071] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    13.071] (II) Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, 0)
[    13.071] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    13.071] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[    13.071] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    13.071] (II) Unloading vesa
[    13.071] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[    13.071] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    13.071] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    13.079] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    13.079] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    13.079] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    13.079] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    13.079] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    13.079] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    13.079] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    13.079] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    13.080] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    13.080]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 0.0.2
[    13.080]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    13.080] (**) FBDEV(2): claimed PCI slot 0@0:1:0
[    13.080] (II) FBDEV(2): using default device
[    13.080] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    13.080] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    13.080] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    13.080] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    13.080] (II) FBDEV(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    13.080] (==) FBDEV(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    13.080] (==) FBDEV(0): RGB weight 888
[    13.080] (==) FBDEV(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    13.080] (==) FBDEV(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    13.080] (II) FBDEV(0): hardware: VESA VGA (video memory: 3072kB)
[    13.080] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against framebuffer device...
[    13.080] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against monitor...
[    13.080] (--) FBDEV(0): Virtual size is 1024x768 (pitch 1024)
[    13.080] (**) FBDEV(0):  Built-in mode "current": 78.7 MHz, 59.9 kHz, 75.7 Hz
[    13.080] (II) FBDEV(0): Modeline "current"x0.0   78.65  1024 1056 1184 1312  768 772 776 792 -hsync -vsync -csync (59.9 kHz b)
[    13.080] (==) FBDEV(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    13.080] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    13.080] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    13.080] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    13.086] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    13.086]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    13.086]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    13.086] (**) FBDEV(0): using shadow framebuffer
[    13.086] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[    13.086] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[    13.087] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[    13.087] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    13.087]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.1.0
[    13.087]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    13.087] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    13.087] (II) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument (Screen blanking not supported by kernel - disabling)
[    13.108] (==) FBDEV(0): Backing store enabled
[    13.116] (==) FBDEV(0): DPMS enabled
[    13.116] (==) RandR enabled
[    13.120] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    13.121] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[    13.121] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[    13.515] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[    13.516] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[    13.516] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[    13.612] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[    13.612] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    13.612] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    13.612] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[    13.612] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    13.628] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    13.628]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 2.10.1
[    13.628]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    13.628]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 22.1
[    13.628] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    13.628] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    13.628] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[    13.628] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    13.628] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    13.628] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    13.628] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1/event1"
[    13.628] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    13.628] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    13.628] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    13.628] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    13.629] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event2)
[    13.629] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    13.629] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    13.629] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Video Bus'
[    13.629] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[    13.629] (**) evdev: Video Bus: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[    13.629] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Vendor 0 Product 0x6
[    13.629] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Found keys
[    13.629] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Configuring as keyboard
[    13.629] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input4/event2"
[    13.629] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    13.629] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    13.629] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    13.629] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    13.629] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[    13.629] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    13.629] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    13.629] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    13.629] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    13.629] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[    13.629] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    13.629] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    13.629] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    13.629] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0"
[    13.629] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[    13.629] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    13.630] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    13.630] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    13.630] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event6)
[    13.630] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    13.630] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    13.630] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/event4)
[    13.630] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    13.630] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    13.630] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Logitech USB Optical Mouse'
[    13.630] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: always reports core events
[    13.630] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[    13.630] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Vendor 0x46d Product 0xc05a
[    13.630] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Found 3 mouse buttons
[    13.630] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Found scroll wheel(s)
[    13.630] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Found relative axes
[    13.630] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Found x and y relative axes
[    13.630] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Configuring as mouse
[    13.630] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Adding scrollwheel support
[    13.630] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    13.630] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    13.630] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/0003:046D:C05A.0002/input/input7/event4"
[    13.630] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Optical Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 9)
[    13.631] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: initialized for relative axes.
[    13.631] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    13.631] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    13.631] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    13.631] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    13.631] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    13.631] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    13.631] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    13.631] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Dell Dell USB Keyboard (/dev/input/event5)
[    13.631] (**) Dell Dell USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    13.631] (**) Dell Dell USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    13.631] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Dell Dell USB Keyboard'
[    13.631] (**) Dell Dell USB Keyboard: always reports core events
[    13.631] (**) evdev: Dell Dell USB Keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event5"
[    13.631] (--) evdev: Dell Dell USB Keyboard: Vendor 0x413c Product 0x2105
[    13.631] (--) evdev: Dell Dell USB Keyboard: Found keys
[    13.631] (II) evdev: Dell Dell USB Keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[    13.632] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb6/6-2/6-2:1.0/0003:413C:2105.0003/input/input8/event5"
[    13.632] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Dell Dell USB Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[    13.632] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    13.632] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    13.632] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    13.632] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB  AUDIO   (/dev/input/event3)
[    13.632] (**) USB  AUDIO  : Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    13.632] (**) USB  AUDIO  : Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    13.632] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'USB  AUDIO  '
[    13.632] (**) USB  AUDIO  : always reports core events
[    13.632] (**) evdev: USB  AUDIO  : Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[    13.632] (--) evdev: USB  AUDIO  : Vendor 0x1130 Product 0x1620
[    13.632] (--) evdev: USB  AUDIO  : Found keys
[    13.632] (II) evdev: USB  AUDIO  : Configuring as keyboard
[    13.632] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb4/4-3/4-3:1.2/0003:1130:1620.0001/input/input6/event3"
[    13.632] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "USB  AUDIO  " (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[    13.632] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    13.632] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    13.632] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    13.633] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Front Mic (/dev/input/event7)
[    13.633] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    13.633] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    13.633] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Rear Mic (/dev/input/event8)
[    13.633] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    13.633] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    13.633] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Line (/dev/input/event9)
[    13.633] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    13.633] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    13.633] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Line Out (/dev/input/event10)
[    13.633] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    13.633] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    13.634] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Front Headphone (/dev/input/event11)
[    13.634] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    13.634] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

That seems to show that it's detecting the monitor. I'm not sure. I haven't been able to figure out what this issue is, and I wanted to only ask here as a last resort once I found myself completely stumped. So here I am. Can *anyone* help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can't install `fglrx` on 14.04.5 because it has HWE backported from 16.04 (more info on [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/1404_HWE_EOL)). 14.04.4 is fine though, `fglrx` can be installed there. You can download it from [Ubuntu old-releases](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.0/) (scroll down for `ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso`). Also, you may [disable HWE EOL messages](https://askubuntu.com/a/817280/255435) (again, keep in mind you won't receive security updates too).

Comment: Since posting thing I've moved the system around a bit have two monitors, both working perfectly. I can't remember what my solution was, though

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried the newer Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS from last week? Since it's a HWE version, aka Hardware Enablement Stack, it comes with new kernel and graphics drivers (X-Server, Mesa, etc). This sometimes solves problems with a certain range of hardware, like graphics cards.

Also, since you mention a VGA cable: have you tried another cable to connect your monitor to your computer? For example, I recently used an analogue VGA cable to connect my LCD monitor to a computer with AMD A6 CPU (also no discrete GPU) and it would just bring a black screen. Like in your case, only the nomodeset parameter worked, but then Linux' graphics driver disables hardware acceleration and higher resolutions.

Then I replaced the VGA cable with a DVI cable, which enables the graphics card and monitor to exchange hardware information in contrast to a VGA cable, and everything worked fine right out of the box. Of course, also a HDMI cable should work well, in case your monitor and computer has got such a jack.

**P.S.** To update an existing 16.04.0 or 16.04.1 installation (without HWE) to 16.04.2 HWE, only one "apt install command" is needed: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: I'm on 16.04.2 right now, with two monitors (one VGA, one HDMI). Both work perfectly.