# Torrent app for ubuntu?

Tags: torrent-client

What do people recommend for a torrent app for Ubuntu 16.04? And how do I install it? I tried downloading one but I couldn't install it? Do I have to type in some code?

Thanks for the replies guys. I might try giving Deluge a try. I'll also read through the posted links (thumbs up).

Comment: See this question too: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8989/33157 (Best Bitorrent client on Linux).

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu comes with [Transmission](https://www.transmissionbt.com/), a fairly simple torrent client. But I prefer [Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/) as it is more feature-rich.

You can install software from the `Software Center` app (by Ubuntu) or just `Software` (by Gnome). Just open one of these, search for the app and click install.

Comment: Is there a user guide for Deluge? I installed it, but I can't get it to connect.

Comment: Here's the official guide: http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide. The connection problem is a whole new question but remember that there are other factors that might be causing the problem such as firewalls, routers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use the Terminal, you could use the synaptic package manager instead.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto

If you need to install synaptic see here:
[How to install Synaptic Package Manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131979/how-to-install-synaptic-package-manager)

EDIT: About the bittorrent client: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BitTorrent_clients#Applications

qbittorrent and azureus (vuze) are popular, but this depends all on your preferences (e.g. having a fat client with a lot of features or a small one that does not consume a lot ressources).

regards